# Does a PCIe Multiplexer/Bandwidth splitter ASIC exist?

Tags: pci-express

I may be using the wrong terminology, but I am looking for something that would let me multiplex multiple lower speed PCIe lanes onto a single higher speed one. For example, 3x PCIe 1.0 lanes onto 1x PCIe 3.0 lane. If I had 1x PCIe 3.0 x8, this would give me 3x PCIe 1.0 x8.

I'd expect that this would be presented to the OS as separate PCIe buses. I could do this in FPGA but was thinking there may be an ASIC for this type of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you’re looking for is a PCIe Switch.

[image]

You provide it with some lanes and assign the downstream ports it offers to slots as desired. More information is available in the [PCIe Basics slideshow](https://www.pcisig.com/developers/main/training_materials/get_document?doc_id=4e00a39acaa5c5a8ee44ebb07baba982e5972c67).

The chip in the picture, PEX 8632, lists some common port configurations in its product brief:

- x4 Upstream, 3× x4 + 8× x2 Downstream
- x8 Upstream, 2× x8 + 2× x4 Downstream
- x8 Upstream, 10× x2 Downstream
- x16 Upstream, 2× x8 Downstream